# Error with OpenAI ChatCompletion: JSONDecodeError and Cloudflare Block

Tags: cloudflare, chatgpt-api, jsondecodeerror

I'm trying to make a tkinter program that works with chat gpt. When the bot is supposed to generate a response, I get these errors (I've only included the significant parts of the long error response):

...

> **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ```
>     <h1 data-translate="block_headline">**Sorry, you have been blocked**</h1>
>     <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="unable_to_access">**You are unable to access</span> api.openai.com**</h2>
>
>         <p data-translate="blocked_why_detail">**This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.**</p>
> ```

I got a new API key and ran the code again with that, but didn't work. How can I solve this problem? Please explain in terms a beginner coder would understand.